# Is the equivalence of mass and energy a direct consequence of SR or not?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass-energy

Special relativity gives us the invariance of four-vectors.  Consistency with Newtonian physics implies the conservation of four-momentum.

The spatial part of four-momentum  is

$P^0=m\gamma(v)$

which can be expanded to second order

$P^0 =\frac{1}{c}\left(mc^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2\right)$

This gives good reason to suspect the equivalence of mass and energy, but is a further hypothesis required to suggest that rest energy, $mc^2$, is **interchangeable** with other forms of energy, as is seen in nuclear fission, etc.?

Comment: Another way to put it - is it a consequence of SR that the spatial part of the momentum four vector is energy, or rather $E/c$, or is that a separate hypothesis?

Answer (score 3):

It is a direct consequence of Special Relativity. The equation

$$E^2-(\mathbf{p}c)^2=(mc^2)^2,$$

which expresses the invariance of the length of the energy-momentum four-vector, makes the relationship between mass and energy when $\mathbf{p}=0$ transparently obvious.

I wouldn’t call that relationship “equivalence”. Mass has energy, but energy doesn’t necessarily have mass. For example, a single photon has energy and momentum but no mass.

Comment: but the distinction between mass and energy is nonexistent regarding gravity sources

Comment: @lurscher In GR, the source of gravity is the energy-momentum tensor. Mass doesn’t even appear in the Einstein field equations. An electromagnetic field has an energy-momentum tensor. It doesn’t have mass, but it creates gravity.